# auto complete in command minibuffer of emacs

Tags: emacs

Which setting needs to be done in init.el file, which allows completing the rest of command if one hit M-x and initial letter of the command.

Infact in need something similar as ido-mode for minibuffer too

Answer (score 3):

The ido-mode for the "M-x minifuffer" is called smex (smex use ido).

Available on the main package repos of Emacs.  Homepage [here](https://github.com/nonsequitur/smex)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about *incremental completion*, i.e., having Emacs automatically complete what you type in the minibuffer, without your having to explicitly request completion (e.g., using `TAB`).

Incremental completion is available in [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles), as well as [Ido](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings#Ido) and [IswitchB](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IswitchBuffers). And `icomplete-mode` shows you completion candidates in a similar way to Ido and IswitchB.

[*Icicles* incremental completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Icompletion) has two aspects:

1. When buffer *`*Completions*` is displayed and updated*, showing you the candidates matching your input -- how soon that happens and what triggers updating
2. Whether and how much your minibuffer *input is expanded* (completed) to reflect the set of matching completions

**Wrt `*Completions*` display** (#1):

You can use `C-#` to cycle among the levels (normal, eager, off) at any time.

- *Normal* means that `*Completions*` is not displayed until you ask for it, but thereafter it is automatically updated as you type/edit your input.
- *Eager* means that `*Completions*` is displayed as soon as you type something that matches at least two candidates.

(There is also an option to show  `*Completions*` from the outset, before you type anything -- useful as a kind of menu.)  You can also specify how long to wait after you type or delete a character before updating `*Completions*`.

**Wrt input expansion** (#2):

*Icicles* is unique in expanding your input to (typically) the [***longest common match***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Expanded-Common-Match_Completion) among all completions, even when completion uses *apropos* matching (that is, regexp or substring -- `S-TAB`), not just *prefix* matching (`TAB`).

There are 4 levels/behaviors for this expansion, plus off (no expansion):

- Off -- this is like Ido and IswitchB: completions are shown, but your input is not completed
- On request -- expand your input only when requested (`TAB` or `S-TAB`)
- On request or sole candidate -- on request or when there is only one match
- Always for `TAB`, on request for `S-TAB` -- `TAB` expands whenever possible; `S-TAB` is like previous
- Always -- expand input whenever possible

`C-"` toggles between two of the input-expansion behaviors that you choose (a user option), and `C-M-"` cycles among all of the behaviors.